# Accessing Google play store

Tags: google-play-store

When l click or try accessing the  Google play store application on my android phone, the system says "server error", what can l do? .Now, l find it difficult to download applications on my phone

Comment: Give us the screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0):

try to clear Play Store's cache, go to Settings → Applications and find "Google Play Store" there and choose the "Clear cache" option.

Comment: This does not work.